# Mediawiki flushes my session variables

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have my own login system. I'm building an extension using the already existing AuthPlugin framework to auto-login users on Mediawiki when they are logged on in my system.

```
// Instanciating a user object
$User = new User() ;

// Mediawiki does not start a session for unsigned users
wfsetupSession();

die($_SESSION['test']);
```

I have set $_SESSION['test'] on my own login system before, but all my session variables seem to just get flushed by Mediawiki. Is there any way I can retrieve those variables? I still remain with the PHPSESSID cookie available, but MW creates its own session ID in another cookie.

Comment: Are you using the same session name in both systems?

Comment: I'm unsure if I'm using the same session ID/Name for both systems. If that answers the question better: I start a session on http://mysite.com and insert a value in the $_SESSION['test'] variable. Now this $_SESSION['test'] var is unavailable in my mediawiki extension that is located in http://mysite.com/mediawiki/extensions/myextension

Answer (score 0):

save session in another variable before call function

```
// Instanciating a user object
$User = new User() ;

$session['test'] = $_SESSION['test'];
// Mediawiki does not start a session for unsigned users
wfsetupSession();

$_SESSION['test'] = $session['test'];
```

Comment: I get an undefined variable error on $session['test'] = $_SESSION['test']